# Javascript not working in the blank window

Tags: javascript, window

Hey guys i'm trying to create a window which opens up when i click a particular numbers of a table column in the main document and corresponding to that the rows in that column open up in a different window. The script to delete the rows in the main document is working but the same script does not seem to work in the window that opens up. I dont know what the problem is.Please help me out here.Thanks.

```
 Window = window.open('','W1','width=700,height=500');
//Window.document.write("<style type='text/css'>table,th,tr{ cellspacing=0;border-    collapse:collapse;border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;}</style>");

Window.document.write('<table id="T1" border="1" ><th width="60">S,no.</th><th  width="110">Name</th><th width="110">Op Name</th><th width="110">ID</th><th width="110">Synonym record numbers</th><th width="60">Total Duplicity weight</th><th></th></table>');
 Window.document.write("<button type=\"button\" value=\"delal\" id=\"delal\" name=\"delal\" onclick=\"delall()\">Delete checked</button>");
 Window.document.getElementById("T1").style.borderCollapse="collapse";
 Window.document.getElementById("T1").style.padding="5";
 Window.document.getElementById("T1").style.backgroundColor="#E0C77A";
 Window.document.getElementById('T1').innerHTML += F+M;
Window.document.write('<script type="text/javascript">function deleteRow1(i)  {if(confirm("Confirm to Delete??")document.getElementById("T1").deleteRow(i);}function delall(){if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the selected rows?")){crows=document.getElementsByName("delcheck");for (i = 0; i<crows.length;i++){if(crows[i].checked){document.getElementById("T1").deleteRow(crows[i].parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);i--;}}}</script>');
```

Comment: what is the output in the new window?

Comment: Set your ending `SCRIPT`-tag in `document.write` like this: `<\/SCRIPT>`, otherwise the original script will stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugged last line:

```
Window.document.write('<script type="text/javascript">function deleteRow1(i)  {if(confirm("Confirm to Delete??"))document.getElementById("T1").deleteRow(i);}function delall(){if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the selected rows?")){crows=document.getElementsByName("delcheck");for (i = 0; i<crows.length;i++){if(crows[i].checked){document.getElementById("T1").deleteRow(crows[i].parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);i--;}}}}<\/script>');
```

Notice also JamieJag's answer, and my comment to that answer. That means, that you have to build up the whole HTML-page by script, using closing tags too. And when you have the stylesheet, you can also remove all inner style settings, and also put in the `document.write` the ìnnerHTML. These are not going to work anyway during page parsing.

Finally add the last line to the script: `Window.document.close();`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a bracket for a start:

```
{if(confirm("Confirm to Delete??")document
```

should be

```
{if(confirm("Confirm to Delete??"))document
```

Haven't checked the rest of the code, but if it contains syntax errors (this and possibly others) then obviously it won't run.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to add basic HTML tags, like `<html>` and `<body>` before `<table>`

Comment: +`<HEAD>` where to put the out-commented stylesheet.